# How to get Term via multiple custom properties through JSOM?

Tags: 2013, taxonomy, jsom, term, term-set

I am trying to get terms by multiple custom properties via JSOM. For example: i have a term with always two custom properties

TABLENAME
DB_ID

I want to query a TermSet or filter a TermCollection by these two custom propertiey like (only as example for explanaition)

```
SELECT TERMS FROM TERMSET_A WHERE CUSTOMPROP.TABLENAME = "tbl_A" AND CUSTOMPROP.DB_ID = 25
```

I found the following code

```
      static Term GetTermByCustomID(string customid)
      {
          Term retTerm = null;

          CustomPropertyMatchInformation matchinfo = new CustomPropertyMatchInformation(Program.clientContext);
          matchinfo.CustomPropertyName = "ID";
          matchinfo.CustomPropertyValue = customid;
          matchinfo.TrimUnavailable = false;

          var terms = termSet.GetTermsWithCustomProperty(matchinfo);
          Program.clientContext.Load(terms);
          Program.clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

          if (terms.Count > 0)
          {
              retTerm = terms[0];
          }

          return retTerm;

      }
```

But this allows me only to query the TermSet by one custom property key/value combination. I also looked at the MSDN for a description of CUSTOMPROPERTYMATCHINFOMRATION(c), but also this seems not to be possible.

Perhaps someone had this problem, too, and could solve it via JSOM?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the function below to get customproperties for a termset in JSOM. The code you mention in your question is more CSOM right? 
You can make the same method but a little deeper to get customproperties for a specific term.
I have a termset "Language" with custom properties.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {    
    var scriptbase = "YOURURL/_layouts/15/";       
    $.getScript(scriptbase + "SP.Runtime.js", function () {    
        $.getScript(scriptbase + "SP.js", function () {    
            $.getScript(scriptbase + "SP.Taxonomy.js", function () {
                 //Call your code here.
                 getTermsWithCustomProperties();    
            });    
         });   
    });    
    function getTermsWithCustomProperties(){
        var context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
        var taxonomySession = SP.Taxonomy.TaxonomySession.getTaxonomySession(context);
        var termStore = taxonomySession.getDefaultSiteCollectionTermStore();
        var termSets = termStore.getTermSetsByName("Language", 1033);
        var termSet = termSets.getByName("Language");
        context.load(termSet);
        context.executeQueryAsync(function onSuccess() {
            var termSetItem = termSet.getTermsWithCustomProperty("TABLENAME");
            var properties = termSetItem.get_objectData().get_properties()["CustomProperties"];
            console.log(properties);
        }, function onFailure(args) {
            alert('Error: '+args);
        });
    }
});
</script>
```

Regards,

Comment: Hi DiscoPlacid, thanks for your code but what i am searching for is not to get the custom properties for a specific term instead i need to find the term by its two specified custom properties.

Comment: Hi, Ok sorry, I understood a little bit later :)
There is a function, as you mentioned below to get terms with custom property in the sp.taxonomy.js 
ex : `var termSetItem = termSet.getTermsWithCustomProperty("TABLENAME");
   var properties = termSetItem.get_objectData().get_properties()["CustomProperties"];`
I tries it but without specific result. You can call the function on the session, on the termstore or on a termset
I've updated the code above, maybe you will be luckier than me :)